# How can i render window close / maximize / minimize buttons in wpf?

Tags: wpf

(Dropping this here, since i couldn't remember the font name and someone else might find this useful.)

What is an easy way to render these buttons

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to do this is using a textblock and using font family "Marlett"

https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Marlett_Characters